# UK Visa Application Following a previous Refusal: Changes to the answers on the form

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

Can we make changes in uk visa new application form for reapplying for tourist visa after refusal of visa?
Do they compare previous application with the new application?
[image]
[image]

---

Additional info from comments which explain the corrective measures (edit by Gayot)

My college letter clearly says that i am enrolled in 4 years program and he has completed 3 years and 1 more year to go.I will also attach my exam results to prove the number of semesters i have cleared. The letter also says that i want to travel to uk during my vacation as the college is having holiday from 2 june to 4 july 2016 and the college has no objection. I have also attached bonafide letter from college. My Father has savings of 2900 pounds and mother has savings of 1600 pounds.

I have a joint account with my father worth 1500 pounds and we are also showing my fathers fixed deposits worth 12000 pounds. And public provident funds worth 5600 pounds in my name,fathers and mothers name combined.That should be enough?

---

For those having a problem with the poor resolution of the scan, it is all very standard formulae...

**First dot point:** she accepts that the cousin has the capacity to provide accommodation, but she needs to evaluate his (the applicant's) personal circumstances (standard text for sponsored applications)

**Second dot point:** she explains that he is a student with GBP 1k to spend, but she doubts his financial capacity is sufficient and notes that he did not provide sufficient evidence (standard text for student applicants).

**Third dot point**: she explains that the father sponsor is diving deep into his life savings to pay for the trip. (standard text for disproportionate expenditure)

**Last dot point**: based on all of that she thinks he will go underground and try to live in the UK (V 4.2 (a) & (c)) and moreover will become reliant on public funds (V 4.2 (e)). Text straight from the manual.

(edit by Gayot)

Comment: Well, you're not going to get an approval if you just submit the same thing again, are you?

Comment: Is it okay if we dont change and provide strong proof for why application was refused?

Comment: Please help me with a example

Comment: @CMaster If i submit the same thing and provide proof for rejection reasons,then what?

Comment: What do you mean by "proof for rejection reasons"?  Please be specific.  Normally if you change your application to reflect the reasons for which the previous one was rejected, we would consider that to be a change in your application.

Comment: They refused my application for following reasons and then i provide documents suppoorting the reasons

Comment: @GayotFow i have posted the refusal letter.

Comment: @GayotFow I have taken letters from my college regarding my education status to prove that i am going to come back to my home country to complete my education.                                           I also have savings and assets in my name.             Account balance on fathers account 2,900 pounds And mothers acccount  1600 pounds,as they will be funding me till i reach uk

Comment: @user42802 If you submit again with new information, then that's changing it, no?

Comment: @GayotFow My college letter clearly says that i am enrolled in 4 years program and he has completed 3 years and 1 more year to go.I will also attach my exam results to prove the number of semesters i have cleared.                              The letter also says that i want to travel to uk during my vacation as the college is having holiday from 2 june to 4 july 2016 and the college has no objection.                                        I have also attached bonafide letter from college.      My Father has savings of 2900 pounds and mother has savings of 1600 pounds.

Comment: @GayotFow I have a joint account with my father worth 1500 pounds and we are also showing my fathers fixed deposits worth 12000 pounds.          And public provident funds worth 5600 pounds in my name,fathers and mothers name combined.That should be enough?

Comment: @GayotFow     What else documents  a student can show to prove that he is going to come back to his home country apart from  education letters from institute and bonafide certificate???

Comment: @user42802 that's a different question altogether. You asked your question and you got an answer. It's not a discussion forum here where comments can go on and on raising new stuff. You should read the answers vis-a-vis your question and then raise a new question if it's necessary.

Comment: @GayotFow It may help me to provide more proof

Comment: The scans are completely illegible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39110/discussion-on-question-by-user42802-uk-visa-application-following-a-previous-ref).

Answer (score 8):

Your question is two parts...

**Can you change the application so that it is different from a previous refused application?**

Yes, that's what they *want* people to do. Part of your refusal notice says that your next application will fail unless there's a change in circumstances, so it's important to emphasize those changes.

**Is your new evidence going to work?**

This, like many visa questions, calls for an opinion. Mine is that your next application will fail also.

1. Granted you are presenting some new evidence but it is not a change
   in circumstances. Your situation is still the same as it was in your
   previous application. I.e., you're a student in reduced
   circumstances with few apparent ties to India and who is reliant on
   two co-sponsors.
2. Your flight tickets will require the depletion of about 10% of your
   *entire family*'s liquid assets. This is outside of the feasibility range. The ECO already noted that this was disproportionate and
   providing more detail about the individual balances does not make it
   proportionate.  In the event you need more, your family may need to
   liquidate their fixed deposits/provident funds and because of this,
   ECO's are reluctant to credit them.
3. You have a letter from your school stating that you are a student
   and they have no objection to your travelling during their break.
   The chances are good that they already checked this out on your
   previous application to be sure you were not deceiving them (Indian
   consulates check everything).  And if the ECO determined that such a
   letter would save the application and prevent a refusal, they would
   have contacted you or they would not have refused (it's really **not** an adversarial process).
4. You were refused on V 4.2 (a) + (c) + (e) which means you fit two
   profiles (1) go underground and try to live in the UK; and (2)
   eventually become reliant upon public funds. You need to fix two hard misconceptions they have about you and your new evidence does
   not do much to fix them.
5. Sponsored applications make the very weakest case for an ECO;
   sponsors can pay for your tickets but neither your father nor your
   cousin nor your school can prevent you from going underground if you
   opt to do so.

Your question history here on TSE indicates that you are experiencing some anxiety about your fresh application and while I sympathize with the need to 'clear one's name', doing it in a hurry can make matters worse. Consider waiting until a more prosperous time.

Note: This is the first answer to your question, it's best to wait until all the time zones have had a chance to put in more answers.

There's more information about capacity and apparent lifestyle here: [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)